# SOAP requests fail with MEX Binding

Tags: c#, soap, iis-6, wcf-binding, windows-server-2003

I have an odd problem with some services. I am not the developer I am the sysadmin.

We have some SOAP services running in a development environment. Some SOAP services started to fail. Here is one example. These are both coming from the same web config.

```
        <endpoint address="http://<URL>/<folder>/service.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="eConsentSvc.IeConsent"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IeConsent" />
```

This one does not:

```
        <endpoint address="http://<URL>/<folder>/service.svc/mex"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingText"
                  contract="MetaDataSvc.IMetaData"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IMetaData">
        </endpoint>
```

This 2nd one throws a 404 error. The error generated is this:

There was no endpoint listening at http:////service.svc/mex that could accept the message.

The obvious difference is the "/mex." The developers insist that this has to be there so it has to be there. Why would it throw the 404 error with the MEX there?

If I remove the /mex then the service runs and generates the XML document it is supposed to create.

Please help. I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

In this endpoint one cannot specify `binding="wsHttpBinding"`
it has to one of the `mex*` bindings, for example: `mexHttpBinding`.
Another way would be to simply add another endpoint `<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>`

```
<endpoint address="http://<URL>/<folder>/service.svc/mex"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingText"
              contract="MetaDataSvc.IMetaData"
              name="WSHttpBinding_IMetaData">
</endpoint>
```